# Duplicate 2 images into 5 on canvas javascript html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I had asked a similar question before however received no answer

I am currently stuck on an output which i am trying to create.

My aim is to use two particular images which then will be used to create multiple copies on a canvas whilst they are moving from the top of the canvas to the bottom - continuously .

I have looked into arrays but have not found how the images can be 'duplicated' for e.g. if i were to use an array to store these 2 images, how would i output 5 of these onto the canvas without manually writing 5 lines?

I have found many codes online however none of them cater for images specifically

Any help would be appreciated

CJ

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fpnjmn3p/

Comment: Apologies, by duplicate i was referring to 2 images from src example red ball and green ball and making 5 appear on canvas - moving top to bottom. Hope that makes sense